# HIghlight month name less than 120 days using conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have month's name from January to December in C5:R5. They do not have dates tied to them, just month names.

What is the conditional formatting formula I can use to highlight the month  which is older than 120 days?

Do I format them as something specific too?
=TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm")=C5 i used this but it highlighted current month

I wanted to highlight "project values" if month is older than july.
[image: example] can this be possible with my above idea?

Comment: what day of the month do you want to use?  For example 2022-26-07 is 120 days  but if you only have July in the cell would that trigger it?

Comment: Hi Scott , i wanted to highlight values which are under "Project" header and older than 120 days . can you please see my image attached in question

Comment: You say days but only have month names.  you need to tell us what day of the month to target.  For example on 2022-11-29 120 days back would be 2022-08-01, would you want August Highlighted even though it is only 3 months back and not 4 months?  Or would you want July highlighted because it is 4 months back from November?

Comment: you probably want: `=TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-4),"mmmm")=C5`  Which will highlight 4 months back.  But if you really want days then: `=TEXT(TODAY()-120,"mmmm")=C5` but again on 2022-11-29 it would highlight August.

Comment: yes i wanted to highlight data which is 4 months back that is from July , i wanted to highlight "July" till " January"  , but is that possible to highlight other rows based on this condition?

Comment: Yes i used that but it only highlights July month? can i highlight for rest months too till January ?

Comment: Yes you can highlight more rows.  You just make your applies to the entire range you want and make the row in the formula absolute: `=TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-4),"mmmm")=C$5`  As to the other the formula would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Try:  `=COLUMN(C$5)<=MATCH(TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-4),"mmmm"),$5:$5,0)`

Comment: one quick question C5 is where November is stored correct? i changed it U7 it is not working? also for this : =COLUMN(C$5)<=MATCH(TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-4),"mmmm"),$5:$5,0) it is higlighting all values i think i am messing up

Comment: I tired changing my formula as below : where H2 is "November" and F:F is column - =COLUMN(H2)<MATCH(TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-4),"mmmm"),$F:$F,0) , it returned false for rows which has to be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but I would advise you not to enter the names of the months, but to convert a normal date into a month name, as you can see in my screenshot:

[image]

Column "A" contains the date.
Column "B" contains the same date, but I use cell formatting to show the month name (format "mmmm", as you guessed correctly).
Column "C" contains the formula `=TODAY()-Bx>=120` for checking the date values.
Column "D" contains the formulaText of column "C".

It's obviously the idea that you use the formula of the "C" column as an input for your conditional formatting.